# Is there some means of expanding the range of a capped reed instrument?

Tags: acoustics, woodwinds, construction

Given the pitch limits of capped reed instruments, I wondered whether some means of expanding the range of such existed. Perhaps with some sort of embouchure mimicking device surrounding the reed, but within the cap. The question assumes that the bore is not changed from the original conical/cylindrical bore native to the instrument(for instance, the crumhorn/rauschpfife, respectively).

Comment: I can't help with an answer, but a full two-octave rauschpfeife would be a thing of wonder! I suspect that if it was possible it would have been done already, but I hope someone can come up with a practical proposal ...

Comment: Well, it'd kind of be cheating :-)  to put mechanical lips next to the reed.  Perhaps you could place two reeds in parallel feeds inside the capped chamber, with different sizes and/or different bores?

Comment: Relative to one's audience, start moving really fast to get that sweet, sweet doppler-shifted high octave (posted as a comment to avoid getting -100000)

Answer (score 1):

It's already been done. George Kelischek's rauschpfeiffen can be "overblown" into the second octave: https://www.susato.com/collections/rauschpfeiffen

Otherwise, no I don't believe it's possible to extend the range past nine notes without fundamentally altering the instrument. I've played some capped reeds with keys which extend the range slightly (a couple notes).

George's Kelhorn is a fine example of such alterations, and might prove to be the ultimate advancement of capped reed design: https://www.susato.com/collections/kelhorns